# Easy script to sell and generate unique passwords to a protected area?

Tags: e-commerce, password-protection

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Three different products-- each one consists of online content, housed within a unique folder.
2. The customer purchases one of the three products, and receives a username/password (or it could be some sort of dynamic link that expires) for that product.

I am not a programmer, but I know enough to get myself in trouble. I thought I could find a simple script where I would just have to change a couple of parameters and be good to go. Surely this has been done before, right?

I need something that will somehow send the info to a payment processor (PayPal is preferable, but Google Checkout could be an option too), generate a unique password or code and email it to the buyer, and of course communicate to the folder where the product lives so that the password/code will work.

Am I crazy? Is this something that I need advanced development skills to pull off? I have been looking at open-source shopping carts to see if one of them has this functionality built in, but haven't been able to find anything.

There ***is*** a PayPal script that is supposed to do this, but I have tried working with it before and it is a real pain...I'm not even sure ultimately that it will work the way I want it too.

Any suggestions are most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

From your description it looks like you are trying to sell digital content.

Both Google Checkout and Paypal have frameworks in place that allow you to securely sell and deliver digital goods.

Please have a look at the doc below for Google Checkout Digital Delivery:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Digital_Delivery.html

Comment: Thanks so much for the response-- I realize now I hadn't looked closely enough at Google Checkout. It looks like it may be able to do what I want. PayPal didn't have a method that worked real well for me, but that Google link looks very promising. Thank you!!